# query result then divide, codeigniter and postgresql

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

How can I make this right?

From Model page

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT masters from table2 where table_id='table2-G' AND psced_id='58'");      
  //masters in an Integer type

if ($query !=0 ){
  //code for dividing
```

but I get an error

```
Message: Object of class CI_DB_postgre_result could not be converted to int
```

What I want to get here is that if the value of $query is equal to 0, I could divide.

Comment: like @fxfilmxf says, use `if ($query->num_rows() > 0)`

Comment: @fxfilmxf If only you put your comment in answer. I could check it. But tnx anyway it works

Comment: `$query->num_rows()` won't give you the value of masters, just the number of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a comment to the original question, but to make it official:

You can check the number of rows returned by the query like so...

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$query is an array, probably an array of arrays, so you need to check its count first, then get the element. Once you have the single element you can check it for 0 and do your divide.